# How much gold do you receive for minion kills over the course of a game?

Tags: league-of-legends

How much gold do you receive for kills for each type of minion (range/melee/anti-turret) and how does this amount scale throughout the game? Also, if someone knows, how do I max money from creeps?

Comment: Hi @aTei, I cleaned up your question a bit to be more readable. I left in the bit you originally posted about maxing money from creeps, but you should probably ask that in a different question about a *specific* champion if you want a certain strategy. The only generalized thing we could probably tell you is just "always last hit."

Comment: This appears to be your first question at a Stack Exchange site. While anyone can up-vote answers to any question, as the question poster you alone have the power to "accept" the best answer to your question. It's the grey check mark beneath the vote count.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'll try to sum up what I found at the [wikia article](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Minions) about minions:

### Meelee Minions

- 3 spawn in every wave
- 20 gold during the first wave on Summoner's Rift
- 29 on Twisted Treeline
- increases by 1 after the first wave
- +1 after every 5 minutes game-time passed

### Caster Minions

- 3 spawn in every wave
- 15 gold on Summoner's Rift
- 22 on Twisted Treeline
- +1 after the first wave
- +1 after every 5 minutes

### Siege Minions

- 1 spawn in every 3 waves *(one every 2 waves after 35 minutes game-time)*
- 40 gold during the first wave on Summoner's Rift
- 36 gold on Twisted Treeline
- +1 every 2-3 minutes

### Increased Gold Income per Kill

There are a few champion abilities that increase the amount of [Gold](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Gold) the caster gets when slaying a minion:

> - Ashe's Hawkshot passively grants her 1/2/3/4/5 bonus gold per kill.
> - Gangplank's Parrrley grants a bonus 4/5/6/7/8 gold if it lands the killing blow to an enemy unit.
> - <strike>Katarina's Voracity grants her an extra 25 gold on each champion kill or assist.</strike>
> - Twisted Fate's Loaded Dice grants him <strike>and his allies</strike> 2 bonus gold per kill.
> - Smite grants 10 gold when used when enhanced by the mastery Summoner's Resolve Summoner's Resolve.
> - In Dominion, Promote will cause the user to gain gold for each of the promoted minion's kills.

### Summary

Like `FallenAngelEyes` said, you gain more gold the more times you manage to do the last-hit or killing blow on a minion. To get most out of a wave of minions just **last hit as many as possible**. If you have to decide between killing a melee minion and a caster minion and you can't get both, go for the melee as if gives more gold. Kill a siege minion whenever possible - they are worth the most.

**Some numbers:** Farming the whole first creep-wave gets you 114 gold, the 3rd wave sums up to 147 gold. Cleaning a whole wave after 30 minutes would give only 36 more gold. Therefore, it may be better to help your team and gain an assist than farming a whole creep-wave.
Another thing to know: the gold received from <strike>neutral monsters in the jungle</strike> and the dragon does **not scale with game time**, therefore killing these becomes less relevant over time.

*Edit:* With the Volibear Patch (1.0.0.130 released 11/29/2011) jungle monsters now give less rewards at the start of the game but scale over time - both difficulty to kill and gold/experience. I'll try to add some numbers as soon as I know them.

*Edit 2:* Katarina's passive no longer grants gold, instead it gives her a reset/cooldown reduction. Twisted Fate's passive no longer affects his allies

Comment: To update the `1 spawn in every 3 waves (one every 2 waves after 20 minutes game-time)` - It is actually after **35 minutes** it goes to one every 2 waves.

Comment: This might need some updates. Katarina's Voracity now reduces her cooldowns by 15 seconds instead. Twisted Fate's passive was revorked and does not influence his allies any more.

Comment: Updated, @TomášZato

Comment: Another change: Twisted fate gains a random amount of 1-6 gold per kill. Ashe no longer get's gold from her Hawkshot.