# NonRanked / Ranked Games: Terms and Tips? GP10? Runes? Bans? Last Hits?

Tags: league-of-legends

Sorry for long question title and all the questions, but for Nonranked / Ranked Games:

**What does GP10 mean? I want to perform well and and people always talk about GP10 and such terms: IE, and WoTA?.**

*How do people decide bans? Is about popularity?*

*What runes are really dominate in Ranked games?*

**Why is lasting hitting important and how do you effectively do it?**

- again sorry everyone, I didn't want to posting all the posts and bothering anyone. I don't mind if you answer one or all the questions. Thank you ^_^

Comment: Tip: Try make ONE question per post. this will help you and others.

Comment: As Michel said, ypu should only make one question par post, the Q&A format is not suited to answer multiple questions at once. Don't worry about having a lot of post, it can only make the questions and answer clearer.

Comment: I figured, even if it didn't fit the format well, it was innocuous enough for an answer. Plus I like typing walls of answer. :D

Comment: I Posted one hell of answer below. take a look, i hope it will help you and others =)

Comment: Thank you so much ^_^ and again thank you all for the posting tips

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is lasting hitting important and how do you effectively do it?

Performing a last hit gives you gold, and LOTS of it. Sometime even more than killing a champion. When the opponent team is good in survivability you NEED to last hit, so you can BUY items.

[One good source about gold](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36758/how-much-gold-do-you-receive-for-minion-kills-over-the-course-of-a-game)

> What runes are really dominating in Ranked games?

None. You can go ranked with full set Gold/10 runes and **[kill them all](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=euMuCRx7qhA)** or follow the champion's rune builds pages and lost.

You need to learn which runes works better for your champion.

> How do people decide bans? Is it about popularity?

Not really. People usually go for the champion they are not good against.

***Example:***

Lots of junglers don't like to go against Shaco, so usually they ban him.

The best way to ban is:

- Ban the one who is good counter of your champion.

***Example:***

Akali is a Terrific anti-carry. so if you play a carry champion, she could be a GREAT ban.

> What does GP10 mean?

Gold per 10 seconds items. They are great for Early game, and also for supports role.

***Example:***

- [Philosopher's Stone](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Philosopher%27s_Stone)
- [Kage's Lucky Pick](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kage%27s_Lucky_Pick)
- [Heart of Gold](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Heart_of_Gold)
- [Avarice Blade](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Avarice_Blade)

[Take a look here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57885/when-is-it-better-to-get-gold-per-10-items-instead-of-saving-for-something-else) It might be of use for you.

> IE, and WoTA?.

- IE = [Infinity Edge](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Infinity_Edge)
- WoTA = [Will of The Ancients](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Will_of_the_Ancients)

Answer (score 3):

- GP10 stands for "Gold Per 10 seconds" items. Examples of these are Philosopher's Stone (5 GP10 plus mana and health regeneration), Heart of Gold (5 GP10 plus flat health), Kage's Lucky Pick (5 GP10 plus Ability Power), and Avarice Blade (5 GP10 and Critical Strike Chance). These are most often purchased by support characters (as they do not last-hit in order to feed that to their AD carry) or junglers (to augment their jungle gold income and remain competitive + get the secondary stats on the items).
- IE and WOTA are acronyms for a couple of popular items - Infinity Edge and Will of the Ancients. IE is a core item on basically every AD carry (i.e. the "Right click on people and kill them" champions) that grants a boost to critical damage dealt; Will of the Ancients is a powerful item for AP carries (i.e. mages) that grants ability power and Spell Vamp - a stat that heals you for a percentage of the damage your abilities do.
- Bans are generally used on champions that are degenerate. A very popular ranked ban at most Elo ranges is Shaco - his ability to counter-jungle incredibly aggressively and his extremely hard-to-see-coming ganks make him a liability to face for almost all team compositions, making him a popular ban. Alternatively, in a situation where you know your opponent (like a tournament/scrim), bans can be used to remove lynchpin pieces of your opponent's strategy.
- Runes are dependent on the champion, and also on the situation, so this is a really hard question to answer.
- "Last Hitting" refers to exactly that - getting the last bit of damage on a target that kills it (and thus gives gold for its death). It is important because you don't get any gold from a target if you did 99% of the damage to it but a creep ends up finishing it off (except for champion kills or global gold effects), and if you're not earning gold, you're not elevating in power and will be a liability. The best way to practice your last hitting is go into a custom game solo and focus on doing nothing but last hitting. Don't attack unless you think the shot will kill - pace back and forth or hide out of range of the enemy minions until you go in for a kill. Eventually you will learn both the time it takes for a shot to fire, the length of health bar that's one-shot range, and other factors involved. As a novice, you want to aim for at least 6-8 CS per minute ("Creep Score", also known as the number of enemy and neutral minions you've last hit), and aim to improve to ~10 per minute as you get better at the game.